# TypeError: can't pickle dict_items objects

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, python-2.x, dill

Why does

```
pickle.dumps({}.items())
```

fail with `TypeError: can't pickle dict_items objects` in Python 3.5.2 but not in Python 2.7.12?

"Pickling" the dictionary with

```
pickle.dumps({})
```

works in both Python versions (and in Python 2.7.12 gives the same output as the command above).

Answer (score 22):

because in python 2.7 `.items()` returns a mere `list` of `tuples`, which *is* picklable.

In python 3.x it returns a `dict_items` object (that doesn't exist in python 2), not picklable (but faster since it doesn't generate a list, it's the rough equivalent of python 2.x `iteritems()`).

But you can force list conversion to simulate python 2.x behaviour:

```
pickle.dumps(list(d.items()))
```

Comment: Not a satisfactory answer (my apologies for bothering after 8 yeras:-); it does not explain why it doesn work (regardless of why it worked on PY2), and the workaround would be useless if the `dict_items` are buried deep in some nested structure.

Comment: after 8 years, really I don't know what you're talking about... `dict_items` object is not picklable probably because of the security feature that python introduces in dict hashes, that would make pickled data invalid on reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the json module it works fine.

i.e

```
json.dump(arr, open(file, 'r'))
arr = json.load(open(file, 'r'))
```

Comment: Sorry that was not the question which is super old.
If I was coding in python right now I would use JSON over the pickle format.
Laters.